# Package 'Microsoft.AspNet.TelemetryCorrelation 1.0.8' was restored

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-core, .net-6.0

Any idea how to solve this.
I tried updating nuget packages. But it did not solve the problem.
TargetFramework is net6.0.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Error is very clear from the error message.

This package doesn't support .Net 6.

It supports only the .net framework, not the .net core. So you should not use it in .Net 6 target framework apps.

[image]

[image]

Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web also doesn't support .Net 6.

[image]

Comment: So what should I use instead? @vivek

Comment: Also it's not a direct reference that I have added. It was referenced by another dependency.

Comment: I have attached all the references to the question.

Comment: Do you know by which package it got added?

Comment: I believe it might come from `System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource`

Comment: which version have you installed?

Comment: It's `v6.0.0.0` . There is another project as a ProjectReference. I'll attach it's references to the project as well

Comment: Sorry it's `Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web` not `Diagnostics`

Comment: it also doesn't support .Net 6

Comment: I can't downgrade the project. What is your suggestion? Also I've updated the question please see

Comment: `Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web` itself only supports .NET Framework, so it shouldn't be in your .NET 6 project in the first place. How long has it been there?